# To add another Database or not to add another Database, that is the questionn

Tags: mysql, database

One of my sites is a social networking site running on MySQL.  I use postal code and country information to geolocate users using a webservice.  This webservice also allows you to download all their many tables of information so that you can access it locally.  My site has gotten big enough that I wish to do this now.

My question is, should I create a new database on my site for all of this postal code and country information and all its tables, or should I incorporate those tables into my existing database for my social networking site?

What are the pros/cons either way?

Comment: What is your reasoning behind using another database

Comment: @ulvund:  It just seems natural considering all those tables and how they are directly related to each other but not directly related to my site.  I just don't know if there are any advantages/disadvantages either way, and I want to make the correct choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd vote in favor of a separate database if you planned to use the data as read-only and put a web service in front of it to access it.  Users would search it based on a small handful of parameters (e.g. address info to get lat/lon data).

I'd say put it in the existing database if you planned to JOIN it with other information in your current schema.

Answer (score 1):

When you're talking about scaling and want to know about other databases like NOSQL, you might find this article interesting: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html

Answer (score 0):

it will live on the same disk probably.

so disk space is not an issue.

if you query the tables in a completely separate manner, then no impact on the existing site.
if you query things together, then easier when all in one database.
overall administration of one database vs 2 is easier.

i think it's a no brainer... they go in one db.